# Regex with java

Tags: java, regex

I need to check for lines that have either one of the following patterns:

```
preposition word ||| other words or what ever
word preposition ||| other words or what ever
```

the preposition may be one of any word in a list like {de, à, pour, quand, ...}
the word may be a preposition or not.

I tried many patterns,like the following

```
File file = new File("test.txt");   
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\bde\\b|\\bà\\b) \\w.*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);          
String fileContent = readFileAsString(file.getAbsolutePath());           
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(fileContent);
System.out.println( match.replaceAll("c"));
```

This pattern match a preposition followed by at least one word before the pipe. What I want is to match a preposition followed by just one word before the pipe. I tried the following pattern

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\bde\\b|\\bla\\b)\\s\\w\\s\\|.*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Unfortunately, this pattern doesn't work!

Comment: Maybe add `+` after `\\w` in your pattern. Singe `\\w` means one alphanumeric character, making it `\\w+` will match one or more alphanumeric characters.

Comment: [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) is a website that might help. It is kind of like a text editor for regex (one of many that can be found on the internet). Not an answer to your question, but it might help

Comment: Could you provide us a simple example of the desired behavior (input/output)?

Comment: You're not entirely clear about what you want, as Tamas has noted, but I think that my answer should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of conciseness, I'm just going to use `prep` to stand in as a preposition that we could be dealing with:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:(?:\\bprep\\b \\w+)|(?:\\w+ \\bprep\\b)).*",
                                 Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

`(?:...)` says to group but do **not** capture
`\\bprep\\b` ensures that `prep` is matched only if it is alone, ie it won't match is for `preposition`
`\\w+` demands **1 or more** `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`
`.*` at the end goes with both of the sets of parentheses

**EDIT (in response to comment):**
`"^(?:(?:\\bprep\\b \\w+)|(?:\\w+ \\bprep\\b)).*"` **is working**, you're just most likely running into the case where you have something like:

```
String myString = "hello prep someWord mindless nonsense";
```

This **will** match since this is captured by the second case: `(?:\\w+ \\bprep\\b)).*`.

If you try these, you'll see that the `^` is in fact working:

```
String myString = "egeg  prep rfb tgnbv";
```

This doesn't match the second case since there are 2 spaces after `"egeg"`, so it can only match the first, but it does not due to the `^`.  Additionally:

```
String myString = "egeg hello prep rfb tgnbv";
```

We've established that a case like this won't match the first, and it also won't match the second, meaning that the `^` is in fact working.

Comment: @Dorsaf Except that you're capturing for no reason.  That's why I suggested the `(?:...)`.

Comment: yes, you are right. This works very well, except that I'm not able to limit the search to the begining of the line, I tried '^(?:(?:\\bprep\\b \\w+)|(?:\\w+ \\bprep\\b)).*' however, this doesn't work!

Comment: @ Steve P. I understood why ^ wasn't working for me. It is because that I put all the file that I was reading in a one String. I have to read it line by line instead and treat each string separately. It's working fine now, thanks

Comment: @Dorsaf You can use `Pattern.MULTILINE` for that.

Answer (score 0):

I thank you all for your answers. In fact, as @Pshemo said, I just have to add + after \w. I thought that \w means word. It works now with the following code:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");   
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\bde\\b|\\bla\\b)\\s\\w+\\s\\|.*|\\w+\\s(\\bde\\b|\\bla\\b)\\s\\|.*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
String fileContent = readFileAsString(file.getAbsolutePath());           
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(fileContent);
System.out.println( match.replaceAll(""));
```

As input for example, I have the follwong lines :

the world |||something here|||other things here

world about |||something here|||other things here

another example ||| something here|||other things here

the final and the last example|||something here|||other things here

Then, supposing that the list of preposition are {the, about}, the out put will be:

another example ||| something here|||other things here

the final and the last example|||something here|||other things here

As you see, I just want to match the two first lines and to remove them.